# Reverse a string using a recursive function

Tags: c, string, recursion, reverse

I am currently studying C and I can't get past this exercise. I must create a recursive function to reverse `string1` into `string2`. Here is my code. I would gladly appreciate your help.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX 100

void reverse(char s1[],char s2[],int n,int j);

int main()
{
    char string1[MAX]="How Are You Mate";
    char string2[MAX]="";
    int n=0;
    int i=0;
    int j=0;

    for(i=0;string1[i]!='\0';i++)
        n++;
    reverse(string1,string2,n,j);
    printf("String-a normal:\n%s\n",string1);
    printf("String-a reverse:\n%s\n",string2);
    return 0;
}

void reverse(char s1[],char s2[],int n,int j)
{
     if(n>0)
     {
            s2[j]=s1[n];
            reverse(s1,s2,n-1,j+1);
     }
     else
            s2[j]='\0';
}
```

Comment: The code does compile fine,the problem is it doesnt show any characters when I print the 2 string.

Comment: s2[] stands for the second string

Comment: @Lind, does the exercise mention any benefit you could gain from using a recursive function to reverse a string in C, whose "strings" cannot be returned easily and therefore do not fit that pattern very well?

Comment: It says the same thing as you said.Using a recursive function does not make a faster program,but still it asks for an exercise with a recursive function.I cant move on without solving this exercise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reversing starts by copying the `n`-th character of `string1` array into `string2`. The `n`-th character happens to be the null terminator. It becomes the first character of your new string, so the string looks empty to all standard C routines, including `printf`.

Calling

```
reverse(string1,string2,n-1,j);
```

from the `main` should fix the problem. The condition in the `reverse` should be changed from `if(n>0)` to `if(n>=0)` as well.

Comment: Thanks this is the answer I was looking for.I made the condition string1[i]!='\0' in the for loop,but I started counting from the first character,and I think thats the problem here.

Comment: I didnt put n-1 on the function but I declared int n=-1.As for the n>=0 that was necessary thanks.

Comment: @Lind Starting `n` at `-1` would work too. By the way, you can drop the declaration of `j` from `main`, because it is assigned zero, and is not changed after that, so you can pass `0` as your last parameter of `reverse` for the same effect.

Answer (score 5):

in-place (the caller could make a copy of the string before calling this function) string reverse with tail-recursion

```
void reverse (char *str, size_t len)
{
  char tmp;
  if (len-- < 2) return;

  tmp = *str;
  *str = str[len];
  str[len] = tmp;

  reverse (str+1, len -1);
}
```

O, if you don't want pointers:

```
void reverse (char str[], size_t len)
{
  char tmp;
  if (len-- < 2) return;

  tmp = str[0];
  str[0] = str[len];
  str[len] = tmp;

  reverse (str+1, len -1);
}
```

Comment: I fixed my original solution,and yes I understand it,although I must read pointers again cuz I don't have a clear idea on them.

Answer (score 2):

Although it does not *save* the resulting string anywhere, you get the idea.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void rev (const char* str);

int main () {
    const char str[] = "!dlrow ,olleH";

    printf("%s\n", str);

    rev(str);
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}

void rev (const char* str) {
    char c = *str;
    if (c != '\0') {
            rev(str + 1);
        printf("%c", c);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have corrected the program. Please find the changes below

```
void reverse(char s1[],char s2[],int n,int j)
{
 if(n>0)
 {
        s2[j]=s1[n-1];
        reverse(s1,s2,--n,++j);
 }
 else
        s2[j]='\0';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i recommend using library , size=strlen(array) in stead of

```
for(i=0;string1[i]!='\0';i++)
n++;
```

to count how many characters in arra